# Is success different for everybody according to Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

For instance, there is a child who is a refugee and is still fighting for his community which is on the verge of extinction due to genocide. What is success when we talk about this child's solution? Or we can say what success really is? Is it only excelling in one's respective field or it depends on an individual's situation/scenario? Does God only sees the intention of the person doing karma or its result too? Everyone says that we should do work selflessly but no one tells what to do exactly? Why am  I here? What's my purpose? Do I have to set a purpose in my life and align all my actions according to it? i am a patriot so how can I implement bg in my life? kindly explain with respect to Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: The Gita is a guide on obtain God. It is not a guide to worldly gain or worldly success. Your question includes multiple questions, the guidelines ask to limit each posting to one question.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I think OP is newbie user's.He don't know  how to ask a question

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: God says not to worry about the fruits (results): कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन। मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि॥ BG. २-४७

Answer (score 1):

If you want to become  a real karma yogi in the right sense  of the term , you will have to keep balanced mind at all times ,in all conditions and under all circumstances.There is no doubt very difficult and require prolonged and patience practice .

A Nishkamya karma yogi says:’ Do all works without expectation  of fruits.This will produce Chitta Suddhi(chitta means 'consciousness' and suddhi means 'purification.' Chitta suddhi can be interpreted as purity of mind).Then you will get knowledge of the self. You will get mokhsa or eternal bliss, peace and immortality”.This  is his doctrine.That is the reason why lord Krishna say to Arjuna:

> “thy business  is with  the action  only , never with its fruits;so let not the fruits of action  be your motive ,nor be thou to  action  attached